# php pdo function pass the results as an array and access

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to fetch all the results from database using php pdo function. This is my select all function query code.

```
function php_select_all($table_name)
{
    global $dbh;
    $select_query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
    $result = $select_query->execute();
    while($row = $select_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $row['user_name'];
        // HOW DO I PASS ALL COLUMN VALUES AS AN ARRAY
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function like this `<?php php_select_all(ADMIN); ?>` .This line executes all user name values. But I want to pass this values an array and access this array to get all datas on another page. how do I pass thess datas into array values? `<?php php_select_all(ADMIN); AND ACCESS ARRAY HERE ?>`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your exact goal.  Can you give an example of the array you want to pass in and the corresponding output?

Comment: `$row` already is an array with all values.

Comment: Why are you declaring `global $dbh` inside that function? What you need here is to return something if you're intending to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the query result from your function.

Your `$row` contains the entire result.

```
function php_select_all($table_name)
{

   - -

    $row = $select_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $row;
 }
```

And loop through the `$row` in another page/function where you are going to implement it.